# Create array with data returned from API response with typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, api, foreach, push

I'm new at learning typescript so
I'm trying to create an array with data that are returned for me from an API.
This is the way the API returns me the information:

```
"balances":[13 items
0:{12 items
"asset":string"BADGER"
"balance":float1200.2723428815757
"depositedBalance":float1590.400428846141
"earnedBalance":float18.04701434825256
"earnedTokens":[1 item
0:{6 items
"address":string"0x3472A5A71965499acd81997a54BBA8D852C6E53d"
"balance":float18.04701434825256
"decimals":int18
"name":string"Badger"
"symbol":string"BADGER"
"value":float127.41192129866306
}
]
```

I need acess all the items from 0 to 13, and acess the earnedToken inside of it, and then transform the key value and the float number in an array of objects.
Something like this:

```
const results = [
  {
    "value":float3423432432432423
  },
  {
    "value":float324324324324
  },
]
```

I know I must use some forEach and probaly push but I need some help, because I'm kinda lost.

Comment: Can you better format the API response? Thanks.
Moreover, the response is in JSON? It look like JSON but I've never seen the value starts with its type (string, float32, ...): You have added this or is the *real* response (copy-paste)?

Comment: This is the real response(copy-paste) and yes, it is a Json.
I just made the numbers of how I want it for an exemple.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean "I just made the numbers". You've added the ```string``` or ```float127```??? Or something else???

Comment: Working on it...

Comment: No I meant, The numbers of this example I gave of how I want the array to be, I just tip random numbers, but it's not an api response, 
const results = [
  {
    "value":float3423432432432423
  },
  {
    "value":float324324324324
  },
]

Comment: I gave you an answer. Can you explain what is wrong  so we can achieve a correct solution

Answer (score -1):

```js
// Example data | DO NOT COPY!!!
const API_RESPONSE_DATA: IResponse = { balances: [{ asset: "BADGER", balance: .1, depositedBalance: .2, earnedBalance: .3, earnedTokens: [{ address: "Test Address 1", balance: .1, decimals: 10, name: "Badger 1", symbol: "BADGER 1", value: .1 }, { address: "Test Address 1.1", balance: .11, decimals: 1010, name: "Badger 1.1", symbol: "BADGER 1.1", value: .11 }] }, { asset: "BADGER", balance: .1, depositedBalance: .2, earnedBalance: .3, earnedTokens: [{ address: "Test Address 2", balance: .12, decimals: 20, name: "Badger 2", symbol: "BADGER 2", value: .12 }] }, { asset: "BADGER", balance: .1, depositedBalance: .2, earnedBalance: .3, earnedTokens: [{ address: "Test Address 3", balance: .123, decimals: 30, name: "Badger 3", symbol: "BADGER 3", value: .123 }] }] };
// END

// --- Interfaces
interface IResponse {
    balances: IBalance[];
}

interface IBalance {
    asset: string;
    balance: number;
    depositedBalance: number;
    earnedBalance: number;
    earnedTokens: IToken[];
}

interface IToken {
    address: string;
    balance: number;
    decimals: number;
    name: string;
    symbol: string;
    value: number;
}
// END

// Reduce into results
const results: IToken[] = API_RESPONSE_DATA.balances.reduce<IToken[]>((results, balance) => {
    results.push(...balance.earnedTokens);
    return results;
}, []);

// Print results
console.log(results);
```

I've used the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method on the API_RESPONSE_DATA array to reduce it to a single array (called results) containing only the `earnedTokens` of all balances.

Note that the `initialValue` of `reduce` is an empty array `[]`.

*The `reduce(...)` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.*

Working example in Typescript Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFEA8EMFsAcA2BTUATaAXaoA+oARAeVADkiAVUAYSIAUBNAQhYCgBjAewDsBnTUAEE6ASQD6AJXABlOkVLTwYgoIqCAXKBETkveD16oAvKADeoAEbRE0bu12aA2uei9DmTQCIAQoIIBxcAlPABpLa1t7TQA6AEYwtGR9XgBLTGQ0bwi7ZBiAJjDkaAAnbgysmxyYgGZCkrK0Ck4Aa2Q+Jxc0NGLdXi8KXQFBLp63UFjQ8Mqo0DiE5HYU2Gs+8YAGMO44XNAfaDQAc2Ri8cneAE9YC05EL18AoNOwgDdrAFcduNAAXzDO7t6-UGQhGvXGcUmVmmn1i8XQCyWK00sTWKM22zu+yOJ1iELCFyuNzufkCEnBExe7xhsR+AF0fn9QK53MSHsEwlDIjD5sk0uVsjNogVQEVSvzoTU6mLGi02qtnEzQW4gfwQQCxnlIQKYcLEotlohVnkNqAtrAdntDsdQJr8ZdrrddvdSTbJq9EB8YrE8nSGWYmW5kB4nSSglqJbM4YleelMtr8lKGhUuZKRfUMk1Wu1QAr9urVp4BqrhvnQNVwynI3lavD9UiyyazRaslaTuW7YTHT5Q2T26B3Z6q9Vfd96d8ANysEAQUgEVhTsAAWmXWm46WKADNoPZeKwUmvjlv7FodHoDKhTKwAJCcnKrETJnKOWmT77z-fro+oB-aszX5lBpo-DFPuByTje8amm8VzHOB0acKksaPjM3DQRYsHXqKSaQahMHFOBWEZrK2YiJmbTPq+74Hpu27fmR3B-leeajKswGgeBt4oWhGFXnqiKGpouHofh15NkBmAgdwYHXgSDriZJ0lXgOOxCRhb7TuAs7ztOOhoG8x4fpwoCjG8iCYLuXB8AIJlmfe9HPqAJjCOIUiyPIijKKogjRJxujRD0en2AAPKRxHPgAfAAFJFNnmRy2oAJSOeFjGxbw0TwG8vAABaRdE+W+dEhEylmvAJeBPSYG8pTGbopnma+YTPuV2lgHQknWXVtkcAYNzINEiCcAcMVdeZ5VAA).